# cannot access srx220 router from browser

Tags: srx

I can't access my SRX220 juniper router from any browser. It hangs for a long time and shows a message like

No data Received.

I can access it through cli prompt and can see the logs. All web management configurations are proper but still giving the above error.

Observed in the messages log like

> **Failed password for root from IP port 14100 ssh2**
>
> **May 21 02:13:45 domain.he.frmt.ca sshd[20200]: Disconnecting: Too many password failures for root**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just router reboot from cli prompt fixed the issue. Issue may be related to DNS cache but not sure.

> ssh **router-public-ip**
>
> **#cli**
>
> **#request system reboot**